Using Docmd.SetProperty for width
I have a search which generates a Table "Found". I wish to vary the width of one of the fields [Title] in the Table display (NOT Form or Report) using VBA. How do I use Docmd.SetProperty for width?  I can't figure out the syntax from what the help files display.
DoCmd.SetProperty Tables![Newfound]!Title, acPropertyWidth = 3000
Gives Runtime error 424 - Object required
DoCmd.SetProperty Title, acPropertyWidth = acPropertyEnabled, 3000
Gives Runtime error 2498 - An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments
DoCmd.SetProperty (Title, acPropertyWidth = 3000)
Gives Compile Error: Expected: =
I just want it to set the width of the Table column "Title".

Did you try this syntax DoCmd.SetProperty ControlName, Property, Value

I don't think DoCmd.SetProperty can be used to set the width of a column in a table.  At least I can't get it to work.
Fortunately, it's easy to do by assigning your value directly to the ColumnWidth property.
Here's is an Immediate window example from my database:
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTable").Fields("id").Properties("ColumnWidth").Value
 672 
CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTable").Fields("id").Properties("ColumnWidth").Value = 700
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTable").Fields("id").Properties("ColumnWidth").Value
 700

So I think this should do what you want:
CurrentDb.TableDefs("Newfound").Fields("Title").Properties("ColumnWidth").Value = 3000

